# Adding different colours to points in map using plotlydash from data frame

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have created a python dash app which depicts different points in a map using a csv file imported as a data frame.
However I cannot depict the pints in different colours based on the values (text) from the csv column named "Type"

Here is the part of code that renders the map.

```
def update_map(df):
traces = []

for type in df['Type'].unique():
    df_by_Type = df[df['Type']==type]
    traces.append(go.Scattermapbox(
    lat=df['Latitude'],
    lon=df['Longitude'],
    mode='markers',
    customdata=df.loc[:, ['Type']],
    hovertemplate="<b>%{text}</b><br><br>" +"Type: %{customdata[0]}<br>" +""+ "<extra></extra>",
    showlegend=False,
    marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=20,
            color=color[type]
            ),
    text=df ['Name'],
    name = type
    ))

return {'data': traces,
         'layout': go.Layout(hovermode='closest',
          height= 900,
          mapbox=dict(
              accesstoken='pk.eyJ1Ijoia29zdGFzc2FuIiwiYSI6ImNsaHJ5aW56OTBrNHgzaW9hMzNiY3lvd24ifQ.PtLxYEMkBft7PXkCgUqpDg',
              bearing=0,
         center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(
                    lat=56.0,
                    lon=-4.0
            ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=5
    ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no data in the question, I modify the example data in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#multiple-markers) to create a data frame and add a column for store type.To color code by type, I further add a code for the store type category. The same is done by adding a color column for the store type.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

mapbox_access_token = open("./mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

lat = ['38.91427','38.91538','38.91458',
       '38.92239','38.93222','38.90842',
       '38.91931','38.93260','38.91368',
       '38.88516','38.921894','38.93206',
       '38.91275']

lon = ['-77.02827','-77.02013','-77.03155',
       '-77.04227','-77.02854','-77.02419',
       '-77.02518','-77.03304','-77.04509',
       '-76.99656','-77.042438','-77.02821',
       '-77.01239']

names = ["The coffee bar","Bistro Bohem","Black Cat",
         "Snap","Columbia Heights Coffee","Azi's Cafe",
         "Blind Dog Cafe","Le Caprice","Filter",
         "Peregrine","Tryst","The Coupe", "Big Bear Cafe"]

types = ['bar','bistro','bistro','bar','cafe','cafe','cafe',
         'bistro','bar','bar','bar','bistro','cafe']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude': lat, 'Longitude': lon, 'Name': names, 'Type': types})
df['Type_code'] = df['Type'].astype('category').cat.codes 

colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
fig = go.Figure()

for type in df['Type'].unique():
    dff = df[df['Type'] == type]
    dff = dff.reset_index()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=dff['Latitude'],
        lon=dff['Longitude'],
        mode='markers',
        customdata=dff.loc[:, ['Type']],
        hovertemplate="<b>%{text}</b><br><br>" + "Type: %{customdata[0]}<br>" + "<extra></extra>",
        showlegend=False,
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=20,
            color=colors[dff.loc[0]['Type_code']]
            ),
        text=dff['Name'],
        name=type
    ))


fig.update_layout(
    height=600,
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=dict(
            lat=38.90,
            lon=-77.02
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=12
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
I modified my code with according to my csv data and it worked